# How validate an array with a dot in key name ? (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

How can I validate this array in laravel validation:

```
"price" => array:1 [▼
           0 => array:1 [▼
                "price.value" => 50
]
```

I tried to use this, but it does't working:

```
'price.0.price.value' => ['required']
```

How can I solve?
I want to note that: I have no choice to change the name "price.value".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you cannot change the name `price.value` you have to [escape the dot](https://laravel.com/index.php/docs/9.x/validation#a-note-on-nested-attributes) since in Laravel array validation a dot means a nested level.
Try to escape the`.` with `\`
Your data:

```
 "price" => array:1 [▼
           0 => array:1 [▼
                "price.value" => 50
]
```

Validation rule with dot escaped:

```
'price.0.price\.value' => ['required']
```

Comment: I have no choice to change the name "price.value"

Comment: so i have edited the response to take this into account

Answer (score 0):

> Example:

```
{
  filters: [{field: '', value: ''}]
}

     
'filters' => 'nullable|array',
'filters.*.field' => 'required|max:60',
'filters.*.value' => 'nullable|max:60',
'filters.*.cond' => 'nullable|max:10',
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
'price.*.value' => 'required'
```